# YouTube player API integration Error NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I am getting this error while integrating YouTube player in my android app. 
Error in on this line - `youTubeView.initialize(Config.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);`

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView.initialize(java.lang.String, com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer$OnInitializedListener)' on a null object reference
```

My Code:

```
private static final int RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST = 1;
    private YouTubePlayerView youTubeView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_you_tube_test);
        //requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        youTubeView = findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);

        // Initializing video player with developer key
        youTubeView.initialize(Config.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
        if (!b) {

            // loadVideo() will auto play video
            // Use cueVideo() method, if you don't want to play it automatically
            youTubePlayer.loadVideo(Config.YOUTUBE_VIDEO_CODE);

            // Hiding player controls
            youTubePlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.CHROMELESS);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
        if (youTubeInitializationResult.isUserRecoverableError()) {
            youTubeInitializationResult.getErrorDialog(this, RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, youTubeInitializationResult.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST) {
            // Retry initialization if user performed a recovery action
            getYouTubePlayerProvider().initialize(Config.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
        }
    }

    private YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
        return (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
    }
```

Comment: can you post activity_main xml

Answer (score 0):

Get a API developer key from google api console and add the key in separate class as below example.

`public class Config {
    private Config() {}
    public static final String DEVELOPER_KEY="AIzaSyAwhK2xxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxE";
}`